# Can I define a sub-domain for a record set at my ISP?

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns, dns-zone, dynamic-dns, dynamic-ip

My ISP for home internet is giving me some kind of DNS record that lets me redirect a name to my dynamic IP address, I set something like

`MYNAME.go.myisp.tld`

So accessing that domain shows my home web server and things like that.
But ... is it possible to use a local server to define all common DNS records like `mail.myname.go.myisp.tld` ?

I cannot seem to do it, I am not sure how DNS works, will my home server be able to respond to `mail.myname.go.myisp.tld` or will a visitor get a ~*no such record* reply directly from an upper server like `myisp.tld` ?

Comment: Instead of using your ISP's name, why not purchase your own for like $12/yr, and point its nameserver to yourself. Then you have a real domain :D

Comment: Having a real domain was not the purpose, I have many domains. I was trying to receive email at that sub-domain name provided by my ISP.

Answer (score 1):

In general, no.

They would need to offer either:

- the ability to add DNS records to their nameservers for your subdomain via some sort of admin panel
- the ability to [delegate](https://serverfault.com/questions/530415/what-is-dns-delegation) management of `MYNAME.go.myisp.tld` to nameservers of your choosing via `NS` records

Comment: So in general `sub.sub.sub.main.domain.tld` is always controlled by the root name `domain.tld` unless it specifies the slaves are able to change their own sub-records ? On my local computer I have bind9 running, I just don't know if I am blocked at upper host.

Comment: @adrianTNT `domain.tld`'s nameservers handle requests for `*.domain.tld`. If `whatever.domain.tld` returns a set of `NS` records, it is considered delegated and *those* nameservers control `whatever.domain.tld` and `whatever.*.domain.tld`.

Comment: did you meant `AND *.whatever.domain.tld` ?

Comment: @adrianTNT Yep, sorry!