# No DNS propagation for government subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting

I have an `mpwt.gov.la` domain hosted on OVH but managed by the lao government. I added an A record to the DNS table of ns101.ovh.net for a public IP I own:

```
Domain: iram.mpwt.gov.la
TTL: 0
Type: A
Target: 202.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

After 5 days, I still have `ERR_Name_not_resolved` in my browser, and when I'm checking for propagation with https://www.whatsmydns.net/ nothing is happening, every name server returns "unknown".

Are government domain names managed differently than others and sub-domain cannot be added through the host?

Comment: Should be the same. What happens when you `dig app.example.gov.la @<your domain's registered DNS servers>`?

Comment: Why is there a TTL with 0 value ?

Comment: This question will be a lot easier to help with if you tell us the actual fully-qualified domain name in question.

Comment: What DNS server did you add that record to?

Comment: I added real info. @Paul Calabro is the command dig iram.mpwt.gov.la@ns101.ovh.net ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This being a 'government domain name' is not a factor. It works just like other domains.

The `mpwt.gov.la` zone is not delegated to `ns101.ovh.net` but rather as seen below:

```
mpwt.gov.la.            3600    IN      NS      ns2.lanic.gov.la.
mpwt.gov.la.            3600    IN      NS      ns3.lanic.gov.la.
mpwt.gov.la.            3600    IN      NS      ns1.lanic.gov.la.
ns1.lanic.gov.la.       3600    IN      A       202.9.76.20
ns2.lanic.gov.la.       3600    IN      A       202.9.76.21
ns3.lanic.gov.la.       3600    IN      A       202.9.76.37
```

(See `dig +trace +add iram.mpwt.gov.la`)

Ie, while you have created a zone with the same name (`mpwt.gov.la`) and added an address record for `iram.mpwt.gov.la` at the nameserver `ns101.ovh.net`, no one will be querying `ns101.ovh.net` as the domain is delegated elsewhere.
It is, however, possible to get this record back if you explicitly query `ns101.ovh.net` directly (see `dig @ns101.ovh.net iram.mpwt.gov.la +norec`).

Unless the domain name owner is going to delegate this to your specified nameserver(s), you should probably ask them to add the record to their zone instead.

Comment: Thanks, great answer. I was missing the concept of DNS delegation: http://serverfault.com/questions/530415/what-is-dns-delegation/530518