# Bind9 forward top level domain

Tags: bind, internal-dns, named-conf

Hi all just starting working professionally with bind9 and dns, say I have an AD/DC server (with dns) running on internal.com but my bind9 is authoritative for sub.internal.com can I do a forward zone to domain.com from my bind9 server as follows?

```
zone "internal.com" {
    type forward;
    forward only;
    forwarders { 10.15.1.1; };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do that, and it will allow your DNS to perform name resolution in the parent domain.

But you will also need a [delegation](https://serverfault.com/questions/530415/what-is-dns-delegation) in the parent zone to tell its name servers that your subdomain is managed by your name servers.